# huxreg - error "no tidy method for objects of class character" when trying to get CI or P.values

Tags: r

I am using huxreg to report some results. I really would like to get pvalues in the output, and confidence intervals. But when I try to add the option, I get the error "no tidy method for objects of class character"

Here's how I made the model:

```
modelA <- glm(dest_flood ~ buyout_flag, data = full_data, weights = weights, family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"))
sandA <- coeftest(modelA, vcov. = vcovCL, cluster = ~subclass)

sandA
z test of coefficients:

            Estimate Std. Error z value           Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -2.214      0.285   -7.75 0.0000000000000089 ***
buyout_flag   -0.926      0.437   -2.12              0.034 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here's where I tried to output it:

```
huxreg(sandA, error_style = c('ci'))
Error: No tidy method for objects of class character
```

Here's some dput as well:

```
dput(sandA)
structure(c(-2.2136659009921, -0.925773000493324, 0.285462997700738, 
0.437220855027741, -7.75465093137142, -2.11740357269688, 0.00000000000000885868080505286, 
0.0342256112495513), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("(Intercept)", 
"buyout_flag"), c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "z value", "Pr(>|z|)"
)), class = "coeftest", method = "z test of coefficients", df = Inf, nobs = 1197L, logLik = structure(NA_real_, nobs = 1197L, df = 2L, class = "logLik"))
```

Comment: [`Various deprecated items have been removed`](https://github.com/hughjonesd/huxtable/blob/master/NEWS.md)

Comment: what do you get if you apply `huxreg()` directly to `modelA` ?